# Siri suggestion apps on iPhone 13 running iOS 16.4

Tags: ios, applications, siri

I can’t find an exhaustive or clear answer to this online…

When setting up a new iPhone 13 Pro with my partner something unusual happened.

When I swiped down on the Lock Screen (after it says that no apps had been downloaded) there were 4 apps showing in Siri suggestions. He said he has never downloaded these apps on this or a previous iOS device, is that possible? I only glanced for a second (after picking up the phone after it dropped on the floor - the apps were Instagram (normal), Hinge and Bumble…

Could the Siri app suggestions be apps that have never been downloaded? He hasn’t had a working iPhone since iPhone 5 (before these apps existed). He has an iPhone 10 on which he was connected with an Apple ID but he doesn’t use it as a working phone (i.e. no SIM).

Essentially, the crux of my question is would Siri app suggestions show apps that have never been downloaded on someone’s Apple ID, let’s say Hinge - based on other characteristics (i.e. popular near you).

Comment: Are you sure the apps aren't there somewhere on the phone? (Check in App Library). Also, if they're aren't here, save a backup of the phone and factory-reset it. Then load the backup.

Comment: I haven’t checked the phone yet - I wanted to avoid that if possible. I guess I’m just looking for someone to say : Siri doesn’t suggest apps that aren’t on the phone -> they were downloaded.

Comment: You just possibly gave the answer yourself.

Comment: :( just wanted to make sure I wasn’t jumping to conclusions

Comment: Alright. It's a good idea.